# margin space showing black color when opacity in react native

Tags: react-native

[image]

```js
<View style={[{
    backgroundColor: this.props.backColorStreak,
    marginHorizontal: 24,
    height: 40,
    borderRadius: 13,
    opacity: 0.5
   }, 
   this.props.shadow
]}>
</View>
```

Showing black color for margins space with opacity value in android

Comment: HI, and welcome to Stackoverflow - please try to include information about what you've tried, including any code.  
That let us more understand how to help you.
[HowToAsk](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I know how to solve this but I need to see your code. Please edit the post and add it thanks

Comment: what is this.props.backColorStreak and this.props.shadow?